# excel vba: missing property of userform

Tags: excel, vba

I call a sub with a userform as parameter. Inside the sub the userform is missing the property Name (and the methods Hide and Show). When I try to print Name I get the Error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method).

```
    ...
    Debug.Print frm07Unfall.Name
    Call uff(frm07Unfall)
End Sub

Sub uff(uf As UserForm)
    Debug.Print uf.Name
End Sub
```

Office 2007 SP3

Comment: The generic userform class doesn't have a Name property (since you can't have an instance of it). You either need to pass as Object, or as the specific userform interface (i.e. `frm07Unfll` here)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Seems I misunderstood Microsoft: "You can pass UserForms(index) to a function whose argument is specified as a UserForm class."

Comment: what reason has somebody to change my text? I do not prefer to get changes from the dark, but like to know the mistakes to avoid them next time.

Comment: Technically that statement is correct - you can certainly do that, but you will then only have available those properties and methods exposed by the generic userform interface.

Comment: @Rory: Your answer is helpful, I think I have understood - not to follow Microsofts way and getting all what I want. My second comment was directed to Ajeet Shah who edited my question, what wondered me very much.